# How many ads banner can i add to android layout?

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout, ads, banner

I want to add second ads banner inside my LinearLayout but my app crashes when insert the second banner.Works well with the external banner into RelativeLayout,but i want to add second...inside ScrollView. What can i do?Here is my code:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000" > 

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

          <TextView

          />

          <ToggleButton

          />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
     >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

 </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>

 <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
     >
</com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do NOT displaying multiple Admob Adviews on a single page. It is against the terms of service. you signed up to Admob with. Unless you want to have your Admob account suspended.

Comment: what if I used adView and Native Ads on the same layout .. adView  have fixed position on the bottom and the Native Ads on RecyclerView is that against the terms of  Admob service

Comment: @MohamedMohamed did you find out the answer of using a fixed banner and adding native ad in a list liew/recyler view, is it permitted?

Answer (score 0):

You can add unlimited advertisements on your page . I don't think there is any limit for that. But its not recommended to do, according to admob rules there must be one advertisement on one page. And for every Adview you can need to define its seperate Layout that can be linear or relative.

Your application is crahing because you didn't set your **TextView** and **ToggleButton**  Layout parameters. Remove them or set their Layout properties. Like

```
         <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

      <ToggleButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Ok.But why crash when insert banner inside the LinearLayout?

Comment: Post your xml that you using . in this xml you not closing your main Relative Layout

Comment: Your code is working on my emulator. can u post your logcat error.

Comment: E/ActivityThread(10476): Failed to find provider info for com.google.plus.platform

Comment: may be due to same adunit call at same time from same ip address. just a guess